# Disable user profile editing for one user in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, edit, profile

I have being looking in internet how can I disable the option of edit profile in Wordpress for a user and I did't find a good way. The problem is that I want that the 95% of users can edit their profiles (address, telephone,...) but there is another 5% that I don't want them to have access to the profile section.
The best solution for me is to select manually the users that I want to disable but I also thought about create a role or a group of users to manage it.

There is no plugin for this and the only thing I have found is the following code but it is not working.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'user_profile_fields_disable');

function user_profile_fields_disable() {

    global $pagenow;

    // apply only to user profile or user edit pages
    if ($pagenow!=='profile.php' && $pagenow!=='user-edit.php') {
        return;
    }

    // do not change anything for the administrator
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
    return;
    }
    if (current_user_can('custom_role') {
      add_action( 'admin_footer', 'user_profile_fields_disable_js' );
    }      
}
/**
 * Disables selected fields in WP Admin user profile (profile.php, user-edit.php)
 */
function user_profile_fields_disable_js() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            var fields_to_disable = ['email', 'role'];
            for(i=0; i<fields_to_disable.length; i++) {
                if ( $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).length ) {
                    $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

You have to substitude the "custom_role" with the name of the role I have assign to the user.
Is that code obsolete or bad? Any idea of how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this in wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't know that page. If anybody is interested can follow this thread here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141743/disable-user-profile-editing-for-one-user-in-wordpress